# PHP Mail Script : What's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, sendmail

I've got the code

```
<?php
$strMailTo = "An Address";
$strSubject = "Plan for Today";
$strBody = "Today is" + date("l");
mail ($strMailTo, $strSubject, $strBody);
?>
```

However when I try and send it in this state, it just outputs 0 in the body. However if I take out 'date("l") it works fine with plain text, so I know where the problem is, just not how to fix it. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're using a `+` instead of a `.`. PHP uses `.` to concatenate strings.

Comment: haha I knew it'd be some really obvious mistake that I've made. I'll choose the first answer as the accepted one, but thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try not adding your strings but concatenate them:

```
$strBody = "Today is ".date("l");
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `.` for string concatenation, not `+`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$strBody = "Today is" .date("l");
```

Otherwise (when using +) it converted to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

String concat in php is done using the `.` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$strBody = "Today is" + date("l");
```

should be

```
$strBody = "Today is" . date("l");
```